# Read Installed Device Driver Details (version, install date, path etc), on Win system

Tags: api, winapi

Can anyone help please in this regard ?
What API's can be used from win32 to get installed device drivers details like
version, installation date, path where installed ?

Regards,
Kedar

Answer (score 3):

The best way is WMI, .NET supports it well with the System.Management namespace.  You'll want to use the [Win32_SystemDriver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394472%28VS.85%29.aspx) WMI class.  I copied and pasted this code from [WMICodeCreator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en), a great tool to experiment and auto-generate the code you need:

```
using System;
using System.Management;  // Project + Add Reference required

public class MyWMIQuery {
  public static void Main() {
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemDriver");

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get()) {
      Console.WriteLine("Driver caption: {0}", queryObj["Caption"]);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Check out the links I left in this post, Win32_SystemDriver has many other properties beyond "Caption".

Comment: Many other properties indeed. Sadly, "version" is not one of them that I can find.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consult the [Setup API function for driver information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms791137.aspx#8e3b4610-5a86-496a-addb-5b38f34f8597).

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something similar (Win32 via .NET).  Here are some links that helped me:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/SimpleSetup.aspx
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/setupapi/SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty.html
http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=360567