# How to Get Driver Install Date?

Tags: winapi, driver, setupapi

How do you get the **install date** of a driver using the Setup API?

---

(This is pretty much the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988113/read-installed-device-driver-details-version-install-date-path-etc-on-win-sy), except that I'm looking for a solution with the **Setup** API, *not* WMI.)

The data I need is located in a value in a key like this:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\ENUM\USB\VID_????\PID_????
    \????????????????\Properties\{83da6326-97a6-4088-9453-a1923f573b29}\00000064
```

However, the `Properties` key is by default inaccessible due to permissions, and I'm *sure* there's a better way to do this with something like `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty`, but I can't figure out how. Device manager does this really easily in the Details tab (it looks as though it's as easy as getting `CM_DRP_INSTALL_STATE`), so it's gotta be easy...

Comment: I would really love to know where you have gotten this information from (i.e. why this GUID is install date). Specifically, I am looking for a description of all `Properties` there. Any hints greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a peek at the XP registry, it seems like the information isn't even there, so it doesn't even do what I needed.